# Carregar dados dinamico dentro do javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Estou tentando carregar dados dinâmicos vindo do BD, mas não aparece.

```
$(function () {
    var divContent = $('#formularioVeiculo');
    var botaoAdicionar = $('a[data-id="1"]');
    var i = 1;

    //Ao clicar em adicionar ele cria uma linha com novos campos
    $(botaoAdicionar).click(function () {
        $('<div class="conteudoIndividual"><div id="formularioVeiculo"><div class="row"><div class="col-xs-5"><div class="form-group" style="margin:0 0 0 1px;"><label class="control-label">Veículo</label><select name="veiculo[]" id="" class="form-control"><?php do { ?><option value="<?php echo $row_rsVeiculo['ID_Veiculo']; ?>"><?php echo $row_rsVeiculo['placa']; ?> - <?php echo $row_rsVeiculo['tipo']; ?></option><?php } while ($row_rsVeiculo = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsVeiculo)); ?></select></div></div><div class="col-xs-2"><div class="form-group" style="margin:0 0 0 1px;"><label class="control-label">Valor</label><input name="veiculoValor[]" type="text" class="form-control" id="" value="" required></div></div><div class="col-xs-5"><div class="form-group"><button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs linkRemover" style="margin:35px 0 0 0"><i class="fa fa-times bigger-110 icon-only"></i></button></div></div></div></div></div>').appendTo(divContent);
        $('#removehidden').remove();
        i++;
        $('<input type="hidden" name="quantidadeCampos" value="' + i + '" id="removehidden">').appendTo(divContent);
    });

    //Cliquando em remover a linha é eliminada
    $('#formularioVeiculo').on('click', '.linkRemover', function () {
        $(this).parents('.conteudoIndividual').remove();
        i--;
    });
});
```

Desteque do RS

```
<?php do { ?><option value="<?php echo $row_rsVeiculo['ID_Veiculo']; ?>"><?php echo $row_rsVeiculo['placa']; ?> - <?php echo $row_rsVeiculo['tipo']; ?></option><?php } while ($row_rsVeiculo = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsVeiculo)); ?>
```

Imagem do resultado. O primeiro campo aparece porque já no form. Os demais campo são adicionados usando o JS acima de acordo com a necessidade.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não vejo onde estás a ir buscar dados ao servidor/BD... (?) Porque não fazes simplesmente um clone da linha que queres duplicar, sem precisar de ir ao servdor? Podes colocar o HTML do que mostras na imagem?

Comment: @Sergio Como assim clonar? Vou postar o código. Momento...

Comment: @Sergio coloquei aqui http://jsfiddle.net/z0b1z7d6/ para ficar melhor a visualização.

Comment: Falta o HTML onde está o botão para duplicar...

Comment: Esta ai. É que estou usando CSS. É o ID adicionarCampo1

Comment: Atualizado http://jsfiddle.net/z0b1z7d6/2/ coloquei o CSS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se o que precisas é de mais linhas vazias podes clonar uma das linhas já na página e colocar no HTML. Por exemplo:

```
$(botaoAdicionar).click(function () {
    var clone = $(this).closest('.row').clone();
    $('#formularioVeiculo').append(clone);
});
```

Uma adaptação ao teu código seria assim:

```
$('#formularioVeiculo').on('click', '.adicionarCampo', function (e) {
    var clone = $(e.target).closest('.row').clone();
    $('#formularioVeiculo').append(clone);

    // adicionar botão para remover
    if (clone.find('a.linkRemover').length) return;
    var remover = clone.find('a.adicionarCampo').clone().removeClass('adicionarCampo btn-success').addClass('linkRemover');
    clone.find('a.adicionarCampo').after(remover);
});
$('#formularioVeiculo').on('click', '.linkRemover', function (e) {
    $(e.target).closest('.row').remove();
});
```

Repara que tirei o ID da ancora e dei uma classe `adicionarCampo` pois esse elemento vai ser clonado e não é prático teres IDs numerados para elementos que têm a mesma funcionalidade.

#### Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/hzcu4or3/

Comment: E para remover?

Comment: Atualmente eu consigo adicionar novas linhas, mas também preciso ter a flexibilidade de apagar a linha desejada.

Comment: @Tiago ok, vou juntar exemplo...

Comment: Blz, muito obrigado.

Comment: @Tiago juntei exemplo

Comment: Vou testar aqui

Comment: Funcionou! Como eu faço para mudar o botão de remover? Veja como ficou http://i.imgur.com/9kcYYdE.png

Comment: @Tiago como assim "mudar"? não ter esse botão? remover o outro? explica melhor pf

Comment: Desculpe, não expressei bem. É que o botão de remover tinha colocado de outra forma. Esse seria o codigo `<button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs linkRemover" style="margin:35px 0 0 0"><i class="fa fa-times bigger-110 icon-only"></i></button>`

Comment: @Tiago nesse caso é só trocar algumas classes: http://jsfiddle.net/hzcu4or3/1/

Comment: Fiz a alteração, mas só muda a cor do botão. Com o codigo que mandei acima, o botão de remover é como esse http://i.imgur.com/2Mkpyn9.png, esse codigo que faz aparecer i icone do botão `<i class="fa fa-times bigger-110 icon-only"></i>`

Comment: @Tiago já sei, é a classe do `<i>` que tem de se mudar para `fa-plus`. 1 minuto...

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23715/discussion-between-sergio-and-tiago).